# Google Analytics 4 and BigQuery: How can I get accurate total_events count by event name

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a trivial task to pull GA4 total events count data from BigQuery from web platforms by subdomain.

When I pull total event count without device.web_info.hostname, numbers are 99% accurate with GA4 interface. However, I get crazy discrepancies when I pull the same data

Here's my query:

```
select
  event_date
  , device.web_info.hostname
  , platform
  , count(distinct case when event_name = 'job_search__search' then concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id'), event_timestamp) end) as event_count_via_concat
  , countif(event_name = 'job_search__search') as event_count_via_countif
  , count(*) as event_count_naive
from `xxx.xxx.events_itable`
where
 lower(platform) = 'web'
 and device.web_info.hostname in ('au.xx.com', 'nz.xx.com', 'my.xx.com')
 and event_name in ('job_search__search')
 group by 1,2,3
```

Neither of these aggregation matches GA4 total_events report... what am I doing wrong?

Results from GA4 & BQ are attached... Thanks everyone for your help!

Here's the screenshot for my results:

BigQuery:
[image: Event count from BigQuery]

Google Analytics 4:
[image: Event count from GA4]

Thank you for your help!